# Will Renesas V850ES/Jx3-E support 1 wire protocol (max detect temp/humid sensor)?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, interface, humidity, renesas

I would like to connect the DATA pin of sensor to Digital I/O pin of a microcontroller. I am confused that in the data sheet of the sensor they have mentioned this:

> MaxDetect 1-wire bus is used for communication between MCU and RHT03. (MaxDetect 1-wire bus is specially designed by MaxDetect Technology Co., Ltd. , it's different from Maxim/Dallas 1-wire bus, so it's incompatible with Dallas 1-wire bus.)

Comment: It's always good to include a reference, I guess it's this protocol: http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/RHT03.pdf. It's really just pointing out their protocol is different (Maxim/Dallas is more well known) so if you go searching you'll probably find Maxim 1-wire drivers. But it should interface OK with appropriate code.

Comment: @Peterj: that's an answer, not a comment :)

Comment: thankyou, maxdetect 1 wire Is it a propitiatory protocol? or do anyone help me regarding selecting the sensor, digital temp and humidity in one module and have digital output and one pin connected to micro controller. I don't have only 3 pins unused. any suggestions please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it mentions that in the [RHT03 Datasheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Weather/RHT03.pdf) it's really just pointing out their protocol is different (Maxim/Dallas is more well known) so if you go searching you'll probably find Maxim 1-wire drivers. But it should interface OK with appropriate code, it just needs a general purpose I/O line. From the datasheet the voltage range is 3.3 - 6 V so either a 3.3 or 5 V microcontroller / supply will be OK.

I've noticed that on the [Sparkfun product page](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10167) for that device they have some sample code available. The code is written in C and for a AT89S52 microcontroller but that should give you a good starting point. The main things will be to work out how to do the equivalent I/O pin control and timing delays for your Renesas device.